# Q: What is the best way to store api keys in a Blazor WASM application?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using a blazor web assembly application that is not asp net core hosted for a personal website. This website is integrated with Contentful CMS which requires an api key, preview key and space id. I am currently storing these inside my own appsettings.json in www/root and accessing them by injecting IConfiguration into my service, and then accessing the values through the GetSection method.

They take the form:

````
    "DeliveryApiKey": "A",
    "ManagementApiKey": "not used",
    "PreviewApiKey": "B",
    "SpaceId": "C",```
````

This is fine for running it locally, but after some researching online, these keys would be readable and visible to users if deployed and dlls decompiled.

What is the best way to store api keys with a blazor web assembly application?
I am wondering if I should create a asp net core hosted blazor project which would give me a server and shared project, but if I were to deploy it, I am unsure if that would work with github actions and netlify if I were to solely deploy the 'server' side of my project.
What is the best course of action?

*Edit, this is how I use those keys to access the contentful CDA. This is the way based off the documentation.

```
        {
            var apiKey = _configuration.GetSection("ContentfulOptions").GetSection("DeliveryApiKey").Value;
            var previewKey = _configuration.GetSection("ContentfulOptions").GetSection("PreviewApiKey").Value;
            var spaceid = _configuration.GetSection("ContentfulOptions").GetSection("SpaceId").Value;
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var client = new ContentfulClient(httpClient, apiKey, previewKey, spaceid);
            return client;
        }
```

Comment: who do they need to be kept secret from?

Comment: Good question - I don't necessarily know, but I think it is good practice to not have keys visible to the user in this case.

Comment: you could encrypt locally using a 'password' entered by the user.  THis way will protect from third parties discovering the keys. Or are they not provided by the user in the first place

Comment: This is a blog so there is no authentication or password entering by the user. I am unsure what you mean 'provided by the user in the first place' though, I need those three keys to be able to use ContentfulClient to make calls and retrieve my entries. Code example: ```var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var client = new ContentfulClient(httpClient, apiKey,previewKey,spaceid);``` And then for example:  ```string apiKey = _configuration.GetSection("ContentfulOptions").GetSection("DeliveryApiKey").Value;```

Comment: Check out a cloud-based key vault service, such as [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/). Similar services are available from your favorite cloud provider.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks for the suggestion @CoolBots but it would be great to not have to use such a service.

Comment: @CoolBots Following is from MS documentation. See this 

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

`The provider isn't supported for managed identity and application ID (client ID) with  client secret scenarios. Application ID with a client secret isn't recommended for any  ASP.NET Core app, especially Blazor WebAssembly apps because the client secret 
 can't be secured client-side to access the Azure Key Vault service."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming back to provide an answer after thinking through the problem. I decided to create a web api  to this project, and write services to consume that which does the dirty work querying ContentfulCDA. All I have to do is deserialize it into whatever I liked. This seems to be the best way forward, as the api keys would be visible on the client side through appsettings.json.

Furthermore, apparently appsettings.json in blazor wasm projects cannot access environmental variables as they are not exposed to the browser, so my idea of using EVs does not work - So the web api is the best way forward, and Azure Key Vault would be the next step in securing those keys.

Tudor

Answer (score 1):

In general, if any *secret* (API key, password, etc) is available on the client (web browser, desktop app, etc), regardless of what the medium is - Blazor WASM included - it's only a matter of persistence before such *secret* is compromised. Encryption is of little help, because you still need the actual clear-text version *at some point* on the client, in order to facilitate access.

I would strongly recommend keeping any sensitive info server-side. In case of a Blazor WASM app, this means a secondary Web API, etc, accessible from the client (yes, that's still a security risk, but a far more typical one - secure APIs are a solved problem, with Identity Framework, for instance, and similar techniques).

I'd still recommend using a Key Vault service for anything really sensitive, even for server-side access (this is primary use case for a key vault anyhow) - it's a much better practice than storing the keys locally, embedded in the app, committed to GitHub, etc.

Take a look at [this video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/on-net/secretless-apps-with-net-and-azure-key-vault) (I promise I don't make a commission off Azure sales, I just  really do think it's a great solution). The video is featuring a Blazor Server app, but the technique is easily adaptable to a Blazor WASM app calling a Web API.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a feeling this will be the way to go. Seeing as this is a blog style website, I dont intend to have any authentication so having a secondary web api and then having to secure it might not (but I will investigate) be the best way forward. I wonder how people who use contentful with react handle storing api keys... , I am waiting on a response from netlify to see if I can use environmental variables to store my api keys. Question - would using Azure Key Vault still allow me to deploy my WASM application through github workflows and netlify?

Comment: @tudor14 I don't see why not. The Azure Key Vault is designed for production environments with CI/CD integration. Of course, test it out to be sure, as specifics of each setup vary, but I think it's definitely possible to make it work.

Comment: I got a response from the guy who maintains the .net sdk for contentful, and it is possible to store the api keys as environmental variables. The only problem is that I do not know how to do that, so I will post another question tomorrow. Based on that response, I will go ahead with Azure Key Vault. Thank you for your comment and this at the moment is the solution. Tudor.